# Alter table command should skip all the empty values postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'm scraping an excel sheet and pushing it to the postgresql database. While pushing, the script is assigning the 'text' datatype to all the columns. There are some datetime fields in the table, so I have to alter them in the date format. The query I wrote for the same is like this:

```
alter table table_name 
   alter column column_name type DATE 
   using to_timestamp(column_name, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
```

The problem here is, in the excel sheet, there are some empty rows. When I fire this query, it assigns a default timestamp to the empty rows.
How can I skip the empty rows while altering the table?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no mention of a default timestamp in your statement, where is the default timestamp being assigned ?

Comment: try :  using to_timestamp(nullif(column_name,''), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');

Comment: exactly my concern. All the empty values are getting assigned to this `0001-01-01 BC`. Is there any suggesstion to remove these values and set the empty row again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a select like this results in

```
select to_timestamp('', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
```

| to_timestamp |
| --- |
| 0001-01-01 00:00:00-00:01:15 BC |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UOyoSKtf)

to skip empty values (not null) use a nullif in your using

```
create table test (
  test varchar
  );

insert into test values (''), (null) ,('10/10/2022')
```

```
select * from test
```

| test |
| --- |
|  |
| *null* |
| 10/10/2022 |

```
alter table test 
   alter column test type DATE 
   using to_timestamp(nullif(test,''), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
```

```
select * from test
```

| test |
| --- |
| *null* |
| *null* |
| 2022-10-10 |